# Python not summing list correctly

Tags: python, list, sum

Python is not summing all items in the list. What did I do wrong?

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the average of inputed numbers and it seems like the `len()` is working correctly but `sum()` is only summing some numbers.

```
numbers = []
More = True

while More:
    xInp = input('Number: ')
    yInp = input('Again?(y/n) ')
    if yInp == 'y':
        numbers.append(int(xInp))
    elif yInp == 'n':
        break

print(sum(numbers))
print(len(numbers) + 1)
print(sum(numbers) / int(len(numbers) + 1))
```

Comment: Are you sure the intent of this code is correct? This code asks for a number, then only add the number to the list if user says "Yes, again, I want to add some more numbers." Is this correct? I think the programf **first** should add the number to the list, **then** ask if the user wants to add some more.

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 5. **Edit**: wait, why would a number be a yes/no choice?

Comment: i edited that, thanks, it was just my sloppy translation to english, probably did it by accident

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the order, you are exiting the program without considering the last value being input. Altering the order a bit will help you solve the issue. Furthermore be careful with apostrophes and doble apostrophes, I've edited that in the answer too, as it will return a `SyntaxError` otherwise:

```
numbers = []

while True:
    xInp = input('Number: ')
    numbers.append(int(xInp))
    yInp = input('Again?(y/n) ')
    if yInp == 'y':
        pass
    elif yInp == 'n':
        break

print(sum(numbers))
print(len(numbers))
print(sum(numbers) / int(len(numbers)))
```

Comment: thanks, the syntax error is just me sloppy translating the code to english, probably did it by accident because it isn't present in my orig code

Comment: Cheers, hope the answer helped you understand the issue and solve it :) Feel free to accept either answer to mark your question as answered.

Comment: Let me check it and solve it if so. Thanks, already edited to provide accurate answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will only add the most recently-entered number to the array if the user selects `y` at the next prompt. Once they enter `n`, the last number entered is not appended to the list.

You need to append the number right after it has been entered, then check if the user wants to add more.

```
numbers = []

while True: # No need for a variable here
    xInp = input("Number: ")
    numbers.append(int(xInp))
    yInp = input("Again? (y/n): ")
    if yInp == "y":
       pass
    elif yInp == "n":
        break

print(sum(numbers))
```

By convention, variables start with lowercase letters. Uppercase first letters are for class definitions (not instances). I had originally changed `More` to `more`, but as mentioned in the comments, it is not even necessary, so I replaced it with `while True`.

Comment: Careful with the apostrophes, this will return `SyntaxError`

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky Good point - hadn’t spotted that - I just pasted the rest in. I’ll fix it.

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky I have made a few changes and tested it and it works now.

Comment: `More` is never used for anything useful. You might as well drop the variable and do `while True:`

Answer (score 2):

You missed the last value in more than one values.

```
numbers = []
More = True

while More:
    xInp = input('Number: ')
    yInp = input('Again?(y/n) ')
    if yInp == 'y':
        numbers.append(int(xInp))
    elif yInp == 'n':
        if xInp:
            numbers.append(int(xInp))
        break

print(sum(numbers))
print(len(numbers))
print(sum(numbers) / int(len(numbers)))
```